# ValueError: substring not found, Why?

Tags: python

The **my_data.txt** file **looks** like this:

```
jim@gmail.com: hello123  
tim@gmail.com: hello1234
```

The program actually *extracts the email address and password* from the **my_data.txt** file really intelligently for a basic programmer at least. But each time I run it, it yells `ValueError: substring not found`, even thou I tried both the string methods: `.index()` and `.find()`.

```
file = open('my_data.txt', 'r')
for line in file.readlines():
        break_line = line.index(':') # OR: break_line = line.find(':')
        email = line[:break_line]
        password = line[(break_line + 2):len(line)]
        print(line.find(':'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you got empty lines in your text file. Try skipping empty lines and lines that do not contain ":" at the beginning:

```py
for line in file.readlines():
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    if ":" not in line:
        continue
    break_line = line.index(':')  # OR: break_line = line.find(':')
    email = line[:break_line]
    password = line[(break_line + 2):len(line)]
    print(line.find(':'))
```

Comment: I did not modify the other part of the for-loop for now. I would suggest to use  `line.split(":")` though...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this code:

```py
for line in file.readlines():
    if line.strip():  # meaning there is a valid line
        print(line)
    
        break_line = line.split(':')  #index(':') # OR: break_line = line.find(':')
        email = break_line[0]
        print(email)
    
        password = break_line[1]
        print(password)
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue was with empty lines

Comment: Great. You found it. Please then accept one of the posts? (or both?) - if it helps you.